# Hiding a surfaceview that overlaps another one

Tags: android, google-maps, video, visibility, surfaceview

In my app I'm using several surface views (for displaying videos and google maps), displayed on the screen in the same time. 
Now I have to add the possibility to change the configuration (position, size and visibility) of these views. Switching the config must not stop the video playback, neither reset the map (we can add kml layers on it).

In this goal, when I switch a config, I just change the position and size of the views I still use in the new config, and I hide the other ones.

The problem is that if I hide a surface view (using setVisibility(View.GONE) on its container) whose position overlaps the position of another surface view in the new config, the surface view which should be hidden is still visible !

For example, we could have a config displaying a video on the left and a map on the right, like this :

[image: Config 1]

And by clicking on the 1, 2, 3 or 4 bar buttons, we change the config (for example, for a config with only a map). The video is still displayed over the map :

[image: Config 2]

Any idea ? I also tried to set the width and height of the hidden surface view to 0, but it doesn't work (it has no effect, whereas setting the size for example to 100x100 does work). Putting the surface view out of the screen (with a negative margin) doesn't work either.

EDIT : Setting a negative margin works on a galaxy nexus, but on a galaxy tab, the surfaceviews are forced to be in screen. Adding the flag FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS make the negative margins working, but then the layout is drawn under the status bar on the phone... Any hint ?

Comment: Did you try `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`?

Comment: Yes, the result is the same :(

Comment: If I use setVisibility also on the surface view itself (not only on its container), I don't have the problem, but the media player crashes, saying "SurfaceTexture have been abandonned !"...

Comment: This is a long shot but if you are using RelativeLayout you can send to back/bring to front your surface view and avoid any visibility options.

Comment: I'm using FrameLayouts. BringToFront is available but it doesn't work...

Comment: That would work on relative layout. Then you are left with one option to set your view parameter way off screen :) in minus something :)

Comment: I think bringToFront of FrameLayout works, but it does not solve the problem. I don't understood your last suggestion, you meant moving the surface view outside the screen ? I tried, it's not possible. I can move it so that a piece of the surface is outside, but if I put all the surface outside, it is brought back inside the screen. Weird :/

Comment: Well in fact setting the margins so that the surface is outside the screen works... On a galaxy nexus. But on a galaxy tab the surface is constrained to be inside its parent. If I put some values that make the surface outside, the code is ignored. For example if I put with=0 height=0, nothing happens (the size and position stay the same). Same result if I put width=100 height=100 and marginLeft:1000...

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue,

I fixed it using `surface.setVisibility(View.GONE)` instead of hiding the container or parentView.